# C# SQL Server like command not working with parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server

I tried the solution presented in many topics on the internet, but none of them work. If I don't use parameter method like is working.  How can fix that?

Here is my C# code:

```
string kosul = textbox1.Text ;
kitapAra("kitapAdi", kosul);

public void kitapAra(string by,string kosul,int like = 0)
    {
        string sql = "select *  from kitaplar where kitapDurum = 0 and @byP like  @kosulP  order by kitapId ";

           DataTable dt = DbOperations.cmd_SelectQuery(sql, new List<string> { "@byP", "@kosulP" }, new List<object> { by,kosul });
           refreshDataGrid(dt);
    }
```

Here is my SQL connect method:

```
  public static DataTable cmd_SelectQuery(string srCommandText, List<string> lstParameterNames, IList<object> lstParameters, bool blsetCommit = false, int like = 0)
    {
        if (blsetCommit == true)
        {
            srCommandText = "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED " + Environment.NewLine + " " + srCommandText;
        }
        DataTable dsCmdPara = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DbOperations.srConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(srCommandText, connection))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    for (int i = 0; i < lstParameterNames.Count; i++)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(lstParameterNames[i], lstParameters[i].ToString());
                    }
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        sqlDa.Fill(dsCmdPara);
                        return dsCmdPara;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return dsCmdPara;
    }
```

I tried them:

```
DataTable dt = DbOperations.cmd_SelectQuery(sql, new List<string> { "@byP", "@kosulP" }, new List<object> { by,"%" + kosul +"%"});
```

or:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(lstParameterNames[i],"%" + lstParameters[i].ToString()+"%");
```

or:

```
"select *  from kitaplar where kitapDurum = 0 and @byP like  %@kosulP%  order by kitapId ";
```

or:

```
    "select *  from kitaplar where kitapDurum = 0 and @byP like  "%" + @kosulP + "%"  order by kitapId ";
```

Comment: You need to concatenate your wild cards to your parameters i.e. ` like  CONCAT('%', @kosulP, '%')` - With that being said, since your comparing two parameters, you may as well do the comparison in c# and save a trip to the server.

Comment: I do agree that there is no point checking if `@byP` is `like @kosulP` in the SQL layer. You would be better off checking the `string` `by` is within the string `kosul` in your application layer, and if it is then run the query `select *  from kitaplar where kitapDurum = 0 order by kitapId`. If it's not, don't run the query.

Comment: yeah I fixed problem solved when i didn't give column name with parameter

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). Using READ_UNCOMMITTED is suspicious as well and I think you don't really understand what it does and what problems it **might** create based on the question.

Comment: Using the read uncommitted isolation is the same thing as putting NOLOCK on every table. This article discusses the potential and probably pitfalls with this. https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere